# how to remove version of iPhone application from apple app store?

Tags: iphone, ios, version, submission

I have uploaded new version of my application before few days and it have got approved by apple yesterday.

I have found that this version is buggy and it is having one major issue.

I had version 1.0 of my application on apple app store and i have submitted(which is approved ) version 2.0 to app store.

is there any way to remove latest uploaded version i.e. 2.0 from apple app store??

I have been searching for its way and have got few scenarios while goggling for it.

1.I can change the release date of the application.Will it be release dat for the application or for the newer version?? In case i will change the release dat of the newer version(2.0) then will version 1.0 be available automatically to users??

2.I can delete the application but is it possible to delete only one version of the application??

Please suggest me ASAP.I need to solve this before users will download application to their iPhones.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: A huge tip is that: click on the "developer rejected" panel.   You will see the build (you want to delete).  Incredibly, the **TINY ICON TO DELETE IT, ONLY APPEARS WHEN YOU MOUSE OVER THE INVISIBLE ICON - it's to your right.**  (It's one of the red "stop sign" icons, like a "-" sign.) Thanks Apple!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Short answer:

You can remove your app from sale altogether (by setting its availability date to be in the far future) but you can't revert back to version 1.0.

You'll just have to release 2.1 with a fix asap and put a note in the reviewer notes box saying that it's an urgent bug fix and requesting an expedited release (they may approve it quicker that way).

---

note that:

[image: app store connect screenshot]

Comment: "Always with Apple what cannot be done." I haven't even clicked Ready to Upload Binary yet and still can't remove the new version.

Comment: Why would you need to? If you don't want to release the update, don't. If you don't want to release that one but may want to release a different update in future, you can replace the details for that version with the details for the next one when you're ready.

Answer (score 17):

5 things to know about remove and re-sell app:

1. Once your app has been approved, its status will appear as "Ready for Sale" in iTunes Connect. However, your app may take up to 24 hours to appear on the App Store. When you choose to remove all App Store territory settings for an app, you will be removing the entire app from the App Store and not just a specific version. The app is automatically released to all App Stores, unless you decide otherwise by deselecting the territories you wish not to be published to.  The app can be "Removed from Sale" by clicking on the "Rights and Pricing" button from the App Summary Page. Then click on the "Deselect All" button to uncheck all App Store territories. Click "Save Changes".
2. After removing all assigned territory checkboxes from your app in the Rights and Pricing section, the status changes to "Developer Removed from Sale" and your app will not be seen on the App Store within 24 hours.
3. To put your app back on sale, click on the "Rights and Pricing" button from the App Summary Page. Then click on the "Select All" button to check all App Store territories. Click "Save Changes".
4. After indicating your App Store territories to put your app back on sale, your status will no longer be "Developer Removed from Sale". Your app will reappear in the App Store within 24 hours as long as your app status is "Ready for Sale".
5. All binary updates must go through the approval process again, regardless of whether the app is LIVE in the App Store or going live after having been removed from sale.

Comment: I just don't want to remove the build but also, want to remove previously submitted app which has been rejected, as getting an error "We noticed that your app icon is identical to the icons of other apps already submitted to the App Store."

Answer (score 1):

To remove an app from sale on the App Store, follow these steps in iTunes Connect:

1) Locate your app within Manage Your Applications.
2) Click the Rights and Pricing button.
3) Deselect all App Store territories.
4) Click Save.

Your app status will then change to Developer Removed From Sale and will be invisible on the App Store within 24 hours. This process is also noted in the iTunes Connect FAQs and the iTunes Connect Developer Guide:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/iTunesConnectGuide

Let us know if you have additional questions about this information.

For any other questions, please use the Contact Us section in iTunes Connect:

http://www.apple.com/itunes/go/itunesconnect/contactus